# force:source:pull fails with Can't retrieve non-customizable CustomObject named: ApexTestResult

Tags: unit-test, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I deployed source to a scratch org, then ran some unit tests locally in the org.

Now when I do `sfdx force:source:pull` I get:

> ERROR running force:source:pull:  Can't retrieve non-customizable
>   CustomObject named: ApexTestResult.

Running `sfdx force:source:status` gives:

> Remote Add      ApexTestResult            CustomObject

Is there any way to get the pull to ignore this type? I tried everything I could think of with `.forceignore` but nothing works.

Does this mean it is basically not supported to run unit tests locally in Scratch orgs?

EDIT: I suspect this may be related to the fact that I created a list view for the Apex Test Results in the scratch org. Haven't verified that yet -- I will create a new scratch org to check.

Comment: I suggest putting this question in the success community / DX Beta:  https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000HTp1 - this does sound like a bug connected to listviews.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation, it appears that ListView is currently not a supported Metadata API Type (for first-generation packages).
See here: [**Supported Metadata API Types**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_supported_mdapi_types.htm)

It is however supported by second-generation packages, which is currently in BETA.
See here: [**Supported Component Types (Beta)**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_plan_component_types.htm#sfdx_dev_dev2gp_plan_component_types)

**In the meantime, you can try one of two things:**

1. Exclude the List View from your source. (see instructions here: [**How to Exclude Source When Syncing or Converting**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_exclude_source.htm)
2. If you don't need the List View, simply delete it from your Scratch Org.